# Knockout foreach with where statement, is it possible

Tags: knockout.js

I have an existing knockout foreach like so:

```
<!-- ko foreach: reportFields -->
<tr>
   <td><span class="hover" data-bind="text: FriendlyName, click:$parent.openField"></span></td>
   <td><img src="img/cross.png" data-bind="click: $parent.removeField" class="delete" alt="Remove Field" title="Remove Field" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

What I need to do is filter the foreach further i.e. I want to check a field of each item to see if it equals 1, 2 or 3.  I tried simply putting a knockout if statement directly after the ko foreach but it fails to work unless I put it after some html code which is a problem as I don't want to show anything unless it matches.

So my question is can I filter the ko foreach in some way with a where statement or something similar, or is there a way to get the if statement functioning without needing to have html before declaring it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `if` binding to `tr` element:

```
<!-- ko foreach: reportFields -->
<tr data-bind="if: SomeField() == 1">
   <td><span class="hover" data-bind="text: FriendlyName, click:$parent.openField"></span></td>
   <td><img src="img/cross.png" data-bind="click: $parent.removeField" class="delete" alt="Remove Field" title="Remove Field" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or you can create a `computed value` in view model that will store `filtered array` and use it in `foreach`:

```
self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.reportFields(), function(item) {
            return item.someField() == 1;
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed observable array.

```
function ReportViewModel() {
  this.reportFields = ko.observableArray(...);
  this.reportFilter = ko.observable();  // bind to dropdown with values 1, 2 or 3

  this.reportFieldsFiltered = ko.computed(function () {
    var filterValue = this.reportFilter();

    return ko.util.arrayFilter(this.reportFields(), function (item) {
      return item.property() == filterValue;
    });
  }, this);
}
```

and then use

```html
<!-- ko foreach: reportFieldsFiltered -->
<tr>
   <td><span class="hover" data-bind="text: FriendlyName, click:$parent.openField"></span></td>
   <td><img src="img/cross.png" data-bind="click: $parent.removeField" class="delete" alt="Remove Field" title="Remove Field" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

By the way, you can just use `<tbody data-bind="foreach: reportFieldsFiltered">` instead of a virtual element.